# Is there a way to detect Runs on the Screen?

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a UserControl which includes a TextBlock.
I want to select the nearest Run inside the TextBlock when I click the control.
'Near' in terms of 'the closest to the mouse cursor'.
But it seems that 'runs' arent really visual Elements so I cannot get the coordinates with PointToScreen. They don't appear in the VisualTreeHelper.GetChild() either.

If I do a 'Mouse.GetPosition(run)' on every Run inside the TextBox, they all got the same coordinates. Which are Identical with the coordinates I get on the UserControl itself.

```
var coords = Mouse.GetPosition(this); // 110,81.53
var points = runs.Select(run => Tuple.Create(run, Mouse.GetPosition(run)))
             .ToArray(); // Every run has also 110,81.53
```

So, any Ideas on how I really get a screen position of those runs?

Edit: Heres how I generate the runs.

```
private void CreateRun(FormString s, bool bullet)
{
    var inlines    = _TextBlock.Inlines;            
    var run        = new Run();         
    var binding    = new Binding("SelectorBrush");
    binding.Source = this;

    run.SetBinding(BorderedTextBlock.BorderBrushProperty, binding);

    if (bullet)  
    {
        run.IsEnabled = false;
        run.Text      = "    • ";
    }
    else  
    {
        run.Tag             = s;
        run.FontWeight      = s.IsBold      ? FontWeights.Bold          : FontWeights.Normal;
        run.FontStyle       = s.IsItalic    ? FontStyles.Italic         : FontStyles.Normal;
        run.TextDecorations = s.IsUnderline ? TextDecorations.Underline : null;                     

        if (s.BackgroundColor != null)
            run.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)swm.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(s.BackgroundColor));               
        if (s.Text != null)
            run.Text = s.Text;
    }

    inlines.Add(run);

    if (s.ForegroundColor != null)
        run.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((Color)swm.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(s.ForegroundColor));

    if (s.FontSize > 0)
        run.FontSize = s.FontSize;

    if (s.IsTitle)  
    {
        run.FontSize *= 1.2;
        inlines.Add(new LineBreak { Tag = s });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is each run a new instance of your UserControl? could you supply the code that is creating your runs?

Comment: No they are all unique Run instances. Hold on I'll add the code to my question.

Comment: am not 100% but I think this is down to you using Tuple.Create. Once you create the Tuple, you cannot change the values of its fields. This makes the Tuple more like a struct.

Comment: That shouldn't matter at all. I only create a Tuple so that i have the run and the according position in one collection. The runs don't even show up when i use the VisualTreeHelper. Which indicates to me that a 'Run' isn't really a visual element. But maybe I am interpreting this wrong.